# SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:2825). While verifying .cer file in python

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, python-requests

I was getting SSL error in python while connecting to a secured url. As a quick work around I passed `verify=false` and it worked. Later I got the .cer file now that file path is given to verify. Now I get

> SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:2825)

What is the problem?

Is it because I gave .cer instead of .pem?
Can I convert .cer to .pem file ?

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Essentially, yes - this "unknown error" is a result of having a `.cer` file instead of a `.pem` file. I just ran into this, with a different line number (`_ssl.c:4025` or so) but otherwise identical symptoms, and using a `.pem` certificate file instead fixed it.

Courtesy of [HUB](https://serverfault.com/users/56333/hub) and [Marcel Friedmann](https://serverfault.com/users/243796/marcel-friedmann) on Server Fault, [here's how to convert a certificate between those formats:](https://serverfault.com/q/254627)

- Open the certificate file with Notepad++ or similar. If it starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`, it's already in the right format - just rename it to `.pem`.
- Otherwise, If you have OpenSSL installed, it's a fairly easy matter:

  ```
  openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
  ```
- If you don't have OpenSSL installed, but do have Java's `keytool`, you can use that, but it's a little convoluted.

  First, find a keystore that won't mind some use. If you don't have one, create one:

  ```
  # create a dummy certificate in the file test.keystore, forcing the keystore to be created
  keytool -genkey -alias test -keystore test.keystore
  # and now delete the cert
  keytool -delete -alias test -keystore test.keystore
  # the (empty) keystore will still exist
  ```

  Then, import the `.cer`-format cert:

  ```
  keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias test -file certificate.cer -keystore test.keystore
  ```

  Finally, export it as `.pem` (making sure it's actually in the right format):

  ```
  keytool -exportcert -alias test -file certificate.pem -rfc -keystore test.keystore
  ```
- If you don't have OpenSSL or Java `keytool`, you'll need to install one of them, or find another way.